# Better way to find data across multiple arrays

Tags: javascript

```
getComponentById: (state) => (componentId) => {
    return state.articles
        .filter(article => Object.keys(article).some(key => {
            return ['maps', 'charts', 'tables'].includes(key);
        }))
        .reduce((acc, article) => {
            acc = article.components?.find(c => c.id == componentId);
            if (acc) return acc;
            acc = article.maps?.find(c => c.id == componentId);
            if (acc) return acc;
            acc = article.charts?.find(c => c.id == componentId);
            if (acc) return acc;
            acc = article.tables?.find(c => c.id == componentId);
            if (acc) return acc;
        })
}
```

Wonder if there's a better way to rewrite this because the list of components might grow so it feels wrong to just keep adding the lines.

Comment: does combining the arrays resolves it for you? ie. [ arr1, arr2, etc... ].filter()

Comment: I assume the id is only going to be in one of the arrays and it is not repeated.

Comment: @epascarello correct, ID is unique.

Comment: @NourAlhadiMahmoud the state contains reactive objects so destructring them will cause it to lose reactivity.

Comment: @eozzy not really, it would be find, you are just looking it up

Comment: I do not understand why you are using reduce. It is going to only ever return the last thing if finds. Seems very odd.

Comment: You can try with ```flat_map``` as well

Comment: @epascarello Using reduce because I need to iterater over articles and ultimately find a single component.

Comment: So you should be using find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `id` is unique can you just look into every key on every article?

If my guess at your data structure is close you should be able to do something like this

```js
let articles = [
  {
    maps: [{ id: 1, name: 'map1' }, { id: 2, name: 'map2' }],
    charts: [{ id: 3, name: 'charts1' }, { id: 4, name: 'charts2' }],
    tables: [{ id: 5, name: 'tables1' }, { id: 6, name: 'tables2' }]
  },
  {
    maps: [{ id: 7, name: 'map3' }, { id: 8, name: 'map4' }],
    charts: [{ id: 9, name: 'charts3' }, { id: 10, name: 'charts4' }],
    tables: [{ id: 11, name: 'tables3' }, { id: 12, name: 'tables4' }]
  }
]


let getComponentById = (componentId) => {
  let result = null;  
  
  articles.forEach(article => {
    Object.keys(article).forEach(key => {
      let component = article[key].find(x=> x.id == componentId);
      if(component) {
        result = component;
      }
    });
  });
  
  return result;
}

console.log(getComponentById(3));
console.log(getComponentById(12));
```

Comment: I think you are missing the part where he filters for specific keys: `.filter(article => Object.keys(article).some(key => {
            return ['maps', 'charts', 'tables'].includes(key);
        }))`
 but you could just add a return statement inside of the forEach loop if key is not included

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure if that filter was functional or a performance thing - if the latter I usually try to avoid little optimizations like that, should be simple to add on the filter like you say though.

Comment: code does a lot more looping that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @IrKenInvader's answer, I copy data from him.

I use `for loop` because once you find a component, you can early return and no need to check the rest of the data.

```js
let state = {
  articles: [
    {
      maps: [
        { id: 1, name: "map1" },
        { id: 2, name: "map2" },
      ],
      charts: [
        { id: 3, name: "charts1" },
        { id: 4, name: "charts2" },
      ],
      tables: [
        { id: 5, name: "tables1" },
        { id: 6, name: "tables2" },
      ],
    },
    {
      maps: [
        { id: 7, name: "map3" },
        { id: 8, name: "map4" },
      ],
      charts: [
        { id: 9, name: "charts3" },
        { id: 10, name: "charts4" },
      ],
      tables: [
        { id: 11, name: "tables3" },
        { id: 12, name: "tables4" },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

const getComponentById = state => componentId => {
  for (let i = 0; i < state.articles.length; i++) {
    const filteredKey = Object.keys(state.articles[i]).filter(key =>
      ["maps", "charts", "tables"].includes(key)
    );
    for (let j = 0; j < filteredKey.length; j++) {
      const foundComponent = state.articles[i][filteredKey[j]].find(
        a => a.id == componentId
      );
      if (foundComponent) return foundComponent;
    }
  }
  return null;
};

const output = getComponentById(state)(12);

console.log(output);
```